# Python: how to go from a regex pattern to a list that includes all individual characters in the pattern?

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I am new to `regex`. If I have the following pattern:

```
white_list_pattern = '^[0-9a-zA-Z ._-]+$'
```

how can I go from that to a list that includes all characters matching the pattern above? This of course doesn't work because it doesn't include all the characters between 0 and 9, for example:

```
white_list = [str(i) for i in white_list_pattern]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *walrus* operator (python>=3.8) can be done with a single comprehension. It is used to get a reference of the `Match` object to get more functionality such as the `group` method.

Precompilation is optional but improve the performance.

From *FaCoffee*'s Answer, here how to get all characters matching the pattern:

```
white_list_pattern = '^[0-9a-zA-Z ._-]+$'
all_chars = [chr(i) for i in range(128)]

# precompile the regex
p = re.compile(white_list_pattern)

# apply the pattern
white_list = [m.group() for c in all_chars if (m:=p.fullmatch(c))]
```

Comment: I took the data from the answer that the OP gave to "its" own question not from the question itself, sorry!

Comment: @Kelly `m.group()` can be replaced simply to iteration variable `c`, thanks for the remark

Comment: No need for the walrus then. Or even for the list comp :-) `white_list = [*filter(p.match, all_chars)]`

Answer (score 0):

For now, this is the best solution I could find:

```py
import re

white_list_pattern = '^[0-9a-zA-Z ._-]+$'
all_chars = [chr(i) for i in range(128)]
white_list = []
black_list = []

for c in all_chars:
   if re.search(white_list_pattern, c): 
       white_list.append(c)
   else:
       black_list.append(c)
```

Comment: better use _raw string_ when dealing with regex; precompile the regex with `compile`; for a line-by-line "search" there is `fullmatch` which is more performant